# Getting Icons for File Extensions in Adobe Air

Tags: flash, adobe, air, desktop-application

I'm working on an Adobe Air Desktop App ATM.

My question is how to get the icon for a given file extension, but without actually loading up a file of such type.

*I had the idea to just create a blank file for the extension and then delete it once i have the bitmap for its icon, but that seemed like too much trouble and kinda inefficient.*

So for example i want to get the icon associated with a .txt file, or .html file. Is their any way of doing such without having to directly reference and existing file , or create a temporary one as mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you didn't find this solution by yourself, please have a look at the [File class](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Filesystem_06.html).

It has an "icon" property which may well be just what you're looking for.

Good luck.

Comment: The documentation URL has changed. Here's an updated URL: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just having to do as i though, just create a temporary file on the desktop with the given file extension, open and close a stream to it (  no need to write anything to it ), then i could access its icon. After which i deleted the file, and all was good.